# Number Theory about least common multiple

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let a and b be positive integers and let [a,b] denote the least common multiple of a and b. Show that there exist integers x and y such that

$$ \left(\frac xa\right) + \left(\frac yb\right) = \left(\frac 1 {[a,b]}\right). $$

I need a nudge in the right direction - not sure where to start.

Comment: Please let me know if I formatted your question correctly on the right-hand side.

Comment: This is just bezout's identity coupled with the fact that $[a,b]=\frac{ab}{(a,b)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $ab = (a, b)[a, b]$, where $(a, b)$ denotes the greatest common divisor. The rest is given by [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).